# What is the best way to Retrieve List from repository interface to DTO list Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, dto

There is class name DailyElectricity which is in DTO package and it contain 
max , min, sum , average with getter and setter

```
public class DailyElectricity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3605549122072628877L;


  private LocalDate date;

  private Long sum;

  private Double average;

  private Long min;

  private Long max;


}
```

there is interface which its job is to get data from database

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
public interface HourlyElectricityRepository 
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<HourlyElectricity,Long> {
  Page<HourlyElectricity> findAllByPanelIdOrderByReadingAtDesc(Long panelId,Pageable pageable);


  @Query("SELECT max(a.generatedElectricity), sum(a.generatedElectricity),min(a.generatedElectricity),max(a.generatedElectricity)  from HourlyElectricity a where DATE_FORMAT(reading_at,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-1,'%Y-%m-%d') and  panel_id=:panelId")
  List<DailyElectricity> getStaticsDailyElectricity(@Param("panelId")Long panelId);
```

}

it complie without any exception but when i call API it give

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.techtrial.dto.DailyElectricity]
```

it can not covert to dto class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no way for spring to figure out how to convert the result of your query to the custom object **DailyElectricity** you are expecting from; in order to make this mapping possible you need to do two things:

1. create a constructor to so you can create a new object and initialize it through the value resulted from each row of you query:

   ```
   public DailyElectricity (Long max,Long sum,Long min,Double average){    
       this.sum=sum;
       this.average=average;
       this.min=min;
       this.max=max;   
   }
   ```
2. then use the following structure for your query in  `HourlyElectricityRepository`

   ```
   @Query("SELECT new com.example.DailyElectricity( max(a.generatedElectricity), sum(a.generatedElectricity),min(a.generatedElectricity),avg(a.generatedElectricity))  from HourlyElectricity a where DATE_FORMAT(reading_at,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-1,'%Y-%m-%d') and  panel_id=:panelId")
      List<DailyElectricity> getStaticsDailyElectricity(@Param("panelId")Long panelId);
   ```

   - Please notice the package name I have used in the Query (*com.example.DailyElectricity*) and make sure you are using the right package name corresponding to you project before testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  a [class-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) (DTO) they must contain a constructor. Try to add it to your DTO.

But it's better to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to avoid boilerplate code:

```
@Value
public class DailyElectricity {
  private LocalDate date;
  private Long sum;
  private Double average;
  private Long min;
  private Long max;
}
```

Another way is to use [interface-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces):

```
public interface DailyElectricity {
  LocalDate getDate();
  Long getSum();
  Double getAverage();
  Long getMin();
  Long getMax();
}
```

IMO it's better to use them because they are simpler and they have some advantages (see the provided manual).

Note that a good practice is to use aliases in queries when you are using projections. They must match with correspondent field names/getters in the projection, for example:

```
"select max(a.generatedElectricity) as max, ..."
```

**UPDATED**

Unfortunately in Spring Boot 2.0+ the class-based projections don't work as [expected](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/586c3d512021af382c348923a0c2851fb57ded59/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/projections/CustomerRepository.java#L58) (unlike SB 1.5+ - see may working [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections)). <s>Until this bug will be fixed we can use DTO [constructor in the query](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).</s>

**UPDATED 2**

I was mistaken - when we are using class-based projections with a custom query we must use its constructor **regardless of the version of Spring Boot**.

Comment: i use this method but it is always null    @Query("SELECT  max(a.generatedElectricity) as Max, sum(a.generatedElectricity) as SUM,min(a.generatedElectricity) as MIN,avg(a.generatedElectricity) as Average  from HourlyElectricity a where DATE_FORMAT(reading_at,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d') and  panel_id=:panelId")
  List<DailyElectricitySecond> getStaticsDailyElectricity(@Param("panelId")Long panelId);

Comment: @pedramezzati what the method do you mean?

Comment: in my service class  List<DailyElectricitySecond> ListdailyElectricity=hourlyElectricityRepository.getStaticsDailyElectricity(panelId);

Comment: @pedramezzati please check my [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections): the [CommentProjection](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/projections/projection/CommentProjection.java) as class-based projection and its usage in this [test](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections/blob/5f8cc6a567ceb65963bff1aa66e576eb223b45b0/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/projections/ProjectionTests.java#L56).

Comment: @pedramezzati and try to change aliases to lowercase.

Comment: i change it but again same                        [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@684c7a96, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: @pedramezzati I realized what was going on - in Spring Boot 1.5+ the repo methods works as expected (try to run my demo), but when I switch it to SB 2.0.4 then tests fails. I think there is a bug in SB2 and we should report it... But any way I recommend you to use interface-based projections.

Comment: dear i am using spring bot 2.0.2 , i will try your project an let you know