# Loading DTO with collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Consignment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private String personId;

    @Column(name = "person_name")
    private String personName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person")
    @Column(name = "cars_owned")
    private Set<Cars> casrsowned = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Cars implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

   @Column(name = "cars_id")
    private String carsId; 


  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person")
    private Person person;

    @OneToOne
    private CarsDetail  carsDetail;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "carsDetail")
public class CarsDetail implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;
}
```

```java
class CarModelDTO {

    String personName;
    List<String> models;
}
```

In the above relation, want to return `CarModelDTO`
JPA query where,

```
@Query("Select CarModelDTO(p.personName, p.casrsowned.carsDetail.model) from Person as p where p`enter code here`.id = :id"))
public CarModelDTO getCarmodelOwnedByAperson(@Param("id") Long id);
```

I tried multiple ways but it gives
`org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already described [Retrieve List from repository interface to DTO list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125369/retrieve-list-from-repository-interface-to-dto-list/52125633#52125633) you should go through the following step :

1. first create a constructor using the fields you want to be returned from the query output
2. in you query you should create new instance of your dto and pass the field from db to new instalnce :

so you need these changes:

### 1. In the constructor:

You should not use a list as `List<String> models;` as you should consider that your dto as a result row of DB. so you need to have a simple `String model;`

```
    public CarModelDTO (String name,String model){    
        this.name=name;
        this.model=model;   
    }
```

### 2. In the @Query:

- you should use multi inner join appropriately
- you should also append your package name to CarModelDTO in the query (here i used com.example you should change it)

  ```
      @Query("Select com.example.CarModelDTO(p.personName, d.model ) from Person as p inner join p.carsowned c inner join c.carDetail d where p`enter code here`.id = :id")) 
      public CarModelDTO getCarmodelOwnedByAperson(@Param("id") Long id)
  ```

Comment: Here one person can have   >=0 numbers of cars and hence the list of string for the model.   1. In the constructor: its present in my code as   public CarModelDTO (String name,List<String> model){    
        this.name=name;
        this.model=model;   }   In the @Query:  package name is also given properly. \n Want to ask p.casrsowned.carsDetail.model is this correct . Can we access like this . \n Also if we join table can we return list as one of the variable in returning DTO

Comment: see, the logic is simple, You are creating A dto corresponding to each row of the db. if you execute native version of your query in db it results in many row, so each row is A DTO. you can not have a single dto with list of model. each row = one instance of row in DB